# Powershell: invoke-expression with "find"-command

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to call DISM.exe via its absolute path which changes dependent on system architecture. Therefore, I store the filepath of dism.exe in a variable and then proceed to execute the wntire command via `invoke-expression`, like so:

```
$dism = "C:\Windows\sysnative\dism.exe"
invoke-expression "$dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:$index"
```

This is working fine. However, I also have to pipe DISM's output into a find command, so I tries this:

```
invoke-expression "$dism /online /get-featureinfo /featurename:$index | find `"State :`""
```

That gives me the error "FIND: Parameter format not correct"
I tried putting the parameter-string for find into its own variable -> nothing.

How can I pass quoted strings inside a call for invoke-expression?

EDIT:
Usually I would use the cmdlet-version of any DISM command (in this case I could use `get-WindowsOptionalFeature`). However, this script is part of an application that is rolled out via SCCM Software Center. The reason I cannot use the cmdlet version here is as folows:
SoftwareCenter is a 32-bit application and thus the powershell-script is also run in 32-bit mode. I have to modify both 32- and 64-bit images. I work around this problem by launching Powershell from the hidden sysnative folder (explanation see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). 
However, since I can't konw in advance wheahter the image I'm modifying is 32-bit or 64-bit, I have to check that at the beginning of my script and then I store the corresponding program path for Powershell in a variable.
Now, I know I can use `invoke-expression` (see code above) to call a command stored in a variable with parameters. I do not know how to do that with cmdlets, since that doesn't give me the possibility to use a custom program path. That is why I had to use the old dism.exe command. I now have a workaround for the whole situation which consists of having a "launcher" script which detect the bitness in advance and then launches my actual script with the corresponding version of Powershell.

The original issue, which is "how can I pass parameters containing quoted arguments to the `invoke-expresion`-command, still stands...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using PowerShell 4.0? If so, [there are DISM cmdlets you can use.](http://goo.gl/bVUetG) Those will return objects and not strings which are easier and more accurate to manipulate/search.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed answer. Usually I would use the cmdlet-version (i.e. get-WindowsOptionalFeature), as you said. I've edited my question, explaining why I can't do that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing " in your find Expression

Try This

```
| find "`"State :`""
```